# How to redirect with anchors in inner pages?

Tags: javascript

I have a landing page with anchors and inner pages. When i click, on anchors in the inner page , ideally i need the inner page go to the main page and scroll to the anchor. Or at least redirect to main page.
I try this:

```
function linksMenu() {

  let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
  for (let anchor of anchors) {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (window.location.path != '/' && window.location.path != '#') {
        location.href = '/'
      }
      let blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href');
      document.querySelector(blockID).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start'
      })

    })
  }
}

linksMenu();
```

But script first try to scroll and then reload, regardless where we are.

Comment: not sure to understand the scope. have you tried by linking to `#myanchorid` ? where it stand for the id of the anchor you want ti link to.

Comment: I work on cms. And menu duplicate on all pages, so this is a problem. if i will not find solution, than display: none for menu and try to add button (with relocate to main page) to inner-page class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

1. Simplest would be Yomna Hesham example below

> Additionally, if the link to your landing page is for example
>   "mywebsite.com/index", and you want to scroll to ,
>   then the redirect link should be mywebsite.com/index#two

2. If you need JS

```
  <script>

    // assuming ur is https://example.com/?section=one

    var callback = function(){
      if (urlParams.has('section')) {
        const section = urlParams.get('section');
        var element =  document.getElementById(section);
        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
          document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      }
    };

    if (
      document.readyState === "complete" ||
      (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)
    ) {
      callback();
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }

  </script>
```

3. Plain HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html class="no-js" lang="">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
<!-- NOTICE: ID in Body Tag. -->
  <body id="top">
  
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  
  <nav>
    <a href="#one">Section 1</a>
    <a href="#two">Section 2</a>
    <a href="#bottom">Bottom Page</a>
  </nav>
  
  <p style="margin-bottom: 3000px ;">
    This paragraph has a huge bottom margin
    so that the page will definitely scoll and
    put the following link below the page fold.
  </p>
  
  <section id="two"></section>
  <section id="three"></section>
  
  <p>
    <!--
        This link will jump back up to the ID:top in
        the document. Since that is the ID of the body
        tag, this link will jump to the top of the page.
    -->
    <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>
  </p>
 <span id="bottom"></span>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additionally, if the link to your landing page is for example "mywebsite.com/index", and you want to scroll to  `<section id="two">`, then the redirect link should be `mywebsite.com/index#two`